# Laravel catch string output when CommandFinished event fires

Tags: laravel

command.php example, something like this:

```
 public function handle()
 {
    $this->info('just an ordinary message');
 }
```

How can i catch this message ***"just an ordinary message"*** outside command (for my example in service provider) where command finished event is fired.

my service provider file:

```
$this->events->listen(CommandFinished::class, function ($event) {
    dump($event->command);
});
```

Comment: Did you tied `dump(Artisan::output());`

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI yeah, but still does not show message. just empty string

Comment: @I.Jokhadze Did you find the answer? Struggling with the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

`CommandFinished`'s output is using `BufferedOutput` 
So you can get the output by using the `fetch()` function

```
$event->output->fetch()
```

Hope that helps you!